# Google Workspace add-on returns HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found, "Cannot POST /"

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-workspace-add-ons

I've followed this [Create a Google Workspace Add-on quickstart](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/quickstart/alternate-runtimes), which worked fine - I could see the add-on returning the card displaying a cat image.

Then per the "Note" at the top of that page, I wanted to replace the Cloud Function with a Cloud Run function. So I followed the [Deploy a Node.js service to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-nodejs-service?hl=en) tutorial and got a Cloud Run deployment that returns [the same card JSON](https://claudews-pxh6fa366q-zf.a.run.app).

But after replacing the `runFunction` URL in `deployment.json` with the URL above and redeploying the add-on (`gcloud workspace-add-ons deployments replace quickstart --deployment-file=deployment.json`), when I open the add-on from the sidebar, I get this error:

```
Error with the add-on.
Run time error.
HTTP error response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Response body: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, `gcloud workspace-add-ons deployments delete quickstart` and deploying again, but still get the same error.

I see the correct `deployment.json` in the [Google Workspace Marketplace SDK under Alternate runtimes](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk_gsao?) -> <kbd>Deployments</kbd> -> <kbd>quickstart</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Deploy a Node.js service to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-nodejs-service?hl=en) tutorial sets up a GET handler. Requests sent to Google Workspace add-ons [use the POST method](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes#validate_json_requests).

Changing `app.get` to `app.post` resolved the issue.